# override signal handler in gtkmm

Tags: gtkmm

I struggled with the following code. My signal handler on_button_press_event() is never called but I have no idea why. Could someone have a look on it? Maybe someone is able to run through the gtkmm lib with debug infos. I only have the pre-installed gtkmm packages which could not be used for debugging into the library itself.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    #include <gtkmm.h>
    #include <goocanvasmm.h>

    bool MyExternalHandler( const Glib::RefPtr<Goocanvas::Item>& item, GdkEventButton* ev )
    {
        cout << "External Handler" << endl;
        return false; 
    }

    class MyRect : public Goocanvas::Rect
    {
        public:
            MyRect( double x, double y, double w, double h)
                //: Goocanvas::Rect( x,y,w,h)
        {
            property_x()=x;
            property_y()=y;
            property_width()=w;
            property_height()=h;
        }

        public:
            virtual void nonsens() {}

            bool on_button_press_event(const Glib::RefPtr<Item>& target, GdkEventButton* event) override
            {
                cout << "override handler" << endl;
                return false;
            }

            bool Handler( const Glib::RefPtr<Goocanvas::Item>& item, GdkEventButton* ev )
            {
                cout << "via mem_fun" << endl;
                return false;
            }

            bool on_enter_notify_event(const Glib::RefPtr<Item>& target, GdkEventCrossing* event) override
            {
                cout << "override enter notify" << endl;
                return false;
            }
    };


    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        Gtk::Main app(&argc, &argv);
        Goocanvas::init("example", "0.1", argc, argv);
        Gtk::Window win;
        Goocanvas::Canvas m_canvas;
        m_canvas.set_size_request(640, 480);
        m_canvas.set_bounds(0, 0, 1000, 1000);


        MyRect* ptr;
        Glib::RefPtr<MyRect> m_rect_own(ptr=new MyRect(225, 225, 150, 150));
        m_rect_own->property_line_width() = 1.0;
        m_rect_own->property_stroke_color() = "black";
        m_rect_own->property_fill_color_rgba() = 0x555555ff;     

        Glib::RefPtr<Goocanvas::Item> root = m_canvas.get_root_item();
        root->add_child( m_rect_own);

        ((Glib::RefPtr<Goocanvas::Item>&)m_rect_own)->signal_button_press_event().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&MyExternalHandler));
        ((Glib::RefPtr<Goocanvas::Item>&)m_rect_own)->signal_button_press_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*ptr, &MyRect::Handler));

        win.add(m_canvas);

        win.show_all_children();

        Gtk::Main::run(win);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your on_button_press_event() method is not an override, because it has the wrong parameters:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#aba72b7f8655d1a0eb1273a26894584e3

Comment: Simply didn't compile if I change to the signature to `virtual bool  on_button_press_event (GdkEventButton* button_event)` because override fails.

Comment: Sorry, yes, your signature is correct for GooCanvas::item. This is indeed not a Gtk::Widget.